# How to asynchronously send JS variable to Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Simple HTML form in a view. I need the user selected value of the form to pass into the active record query when the user switches it. (Probably not params because then it won't be asynchronous?)

In the example below I need the business_id to be the value of the form. New to rails, so if you could provide some in page javascript, I'll deal with refactoring it to the resources later...

```
<select name="clients">
  <option value="1">Tesla</option>
  <option value="4">Chevy</option>
</select>

<table>
  <% @clients.where(month_year:'2015-02',business_id:'NEED VALUE OF HTML FORM HERE').find_each do |client| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= client.month_year %></td>
      <td><%= client.business_id %></td>
      <td><%= client.bill_charge %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't put the HTML value in there as the Ruby is processed before the page is rendered and user action comes after that. You need to use AJAX to send the selection and return the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expound on other answers, here's a (perhaps) overly simplified mock up.

***Client view***
Here you need to call `render` that points to a partial.  This partial will contain the table data (so it's resuable later).  You also need to give your select statement a class that jquery can easily grab to do the async fetch of your client data.

```
# app/views/clients/index.html.erb
<%= select_tag "business", options_from_collection_for_select(Business.all, "id", "name"), class: "car-select" %>

<div class="clients-table">
  <%= render "table_list" %>
</div>
```

***Table Partial***
With the table you just cut out of the index view, you'll need to paste into a partial

```
# app/views/clients/_table_list.html.erb
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month year</th>
      <th>Business</th>
      <th>Bill charge</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= client.month_year %></td>
        <td><%= client.business.try(:name) %></td>
        <td><%= client.bill_charge %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***AJAX script***
This need to watch for changes to the select and submit a request for client data

```
# app/assets/javascripts/clients.coffee
ready = ->

  $('.car-select').on 'change', ->
    bid = $(this).val()
    $.ajax
      url: '/businesses/' + bid
      dataType: 'script'
    return
  return

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
# this is turbolinks-friendly
```

***Businesses Controller processes request***
In your ajax request you are calling to a URL like, "http://yourapp.com/businesses/23", which really hits the `show` action of your businesses controller.  You want to do it this way because it's completely RESTful and you don't have to change any routes.  But you will need to edit the action to provide an instance variable for clients.

```
# app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb
def show
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  @clients = @business.clients (this assumes that you already have a proper has_many / belongs_to relationship between business and client)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

***UJS View***
The last piece of the puzzle is the UJS view.  This is javascript that is only called when the js request type is sent to a particular controller action.  In this case, the show action of the businesses controller.  This is going to take the newly created `@clients` and replace the existing table with the partial and new data.

```
#app/views/businesses/show.js.erb
$(".clients-table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render( '/clients/table_list', client: @clients)) %>");
```

If you still have questions, or want to do more complicated things, you should go research a little on UJS templates and callbacks.

Comment: Wow.. all that to pass a selection value.. I miss node.js already but have to use rails... Great answer btw

Comment: but you're not just passing a selection value.  you're also querying the server for a list of object and then something has to process that return.  you COULD do it all in a js callback and for the ujs part, and process it as JSON where you pick out the json and update the table.

Answer (score 0):

- put your result table into a partial.
- fire a ajax request on the on change event of the select
- render the table based on the value of the select which you pass as request variable (`@clients')